# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I get this message error there

```
angular.forEach($scope.curriculums, function (item) {
            if ($scope.formData.SchoolCurriculums.includes(item.CurriculumId)) {
                item.checked = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `$scope.formData.SchoolCurriculums` is undefined

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ty so much